# Drupal 7 email not accessing

Tags: email, drupal-7

I have install Drupal 7 and when I go to register from another user not admin. This error is show on screen..
"Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists."

Comment: On which OS are you working?

Comment: hallo dba i want to do it window 7..can you give any suguessitioin in this problem....thanks and cheers.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on local server then there is no configuration of **SMTP**[Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) is an Internet standard for electronic mail (e-mail) transmission across Internet Protocol (IP) networks] so it gives this
Error i-e "Unable to send e-mail". If you configured SMTP then this error will be automatically removed. And the e-mail be sent to the specified user.
From Tajdar Khan

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that can be easily solved with the [SMTP](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module.

Taken from the SMTP module page

```
This module allows Drupal to bypass the PHP mail() function and send email 
directly to an SMTP server. 
The module supports SMTP authentication and can even connect to servers 
using SSL if supported by PHP.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to check that every email address used in the system was correct: the site email (in configuration/siteinformation), MimeEmail, the administrator's email, ubercart store setting email, and any emails in products, and in the end found the email was wrong in my Protected Node setting- which is in fact the module which was trying to send mail.  Check first for email addresses in the module that is triggering the error.